# In kubectl python client how to get storage class by name in yaml format

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to get yaml for the particular storage class using Kubernetes python client, following code does the job:

```
list_storage_class = v1.list_storage_class(_preload_content=False)
storageclass = list_storage_class.read().decode('utf-8') # <class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>
print(json.dumps(json.loads(storageclass),indent=2))
```

Is it a way to specify storage class with the call? On the same hand is it possible to get response directly in yaml conforming to `k get sc NAME -o yaml` ?

Comment: Do you want to just print the YAML, or you want to do something with it?

Comment: I want to get the YAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`StorageV1API`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/StorageV1Api.md) documentation. To get a single `StorageClass`, you want the `read_storage_class` method:

```
>>> from kubernetes import client, config
>>> config.load_kube_config()
>>> v1 = client.StorageV1Api()
>>> sc = v1.read_storage_class('ocs-external-storagecluster-ceph-rbd')
>>> sc.metadata.name
'ocs-external-storagecluster-ceph-rbd'
```

If you want to dump the result to a YAML document:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> print(yaml.safe_dump(sc.to_dict()))
allow_volume_expansion: true
allowed_topologies: null
api_version: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    description: Provides RWO Filesystem volumes, and RWO and RWX Block volumes
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: 'true'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: cluster-resources-ocp-staging
...
```